# Incorporate Discourse into existing rails/heroku app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, discourse

I have an existing rails app and I want to add a community page (powered by [discourse](https://github.com/discourse/discourse)). Ideally at example.com/community

Can someone recommend a method or guide to add this to my existing app? Usually I would just add a gem or something. I don't quite understand the [setup guide](https://github.com/discourse/discourse/blob/master/docs/DEVELOPER-ADVANCED.md) in the docs.

Is it as simple as cloning the discourse project folder inside my existing rails app, and then pointing example.com/community route to the discourse folder?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Discourse is a standalone RoR application and is supposed to be run as such. If I would have a need to provide a community page with Discourse for my existing application, then I would look into my web server's manual pages how to setup "/community" virtual directory for "example.com" host to point to Discourse's code base.

My personal choice of a web server is Nginx, however any other web server should also support "Virtual Directory" feature. Here is my example Nginx configuration for your case:

```
server {
    server_name www.example.com;
    root /var/www/app;
    location / {
        # will execute your application's code, specified by the root above
    }
    location /community {
        # will execute Discourse's code, whenever a user navigates to /community
        root /var/www/discourse;
    }
}
```

I'm not very familiar with Heroku platform and whether or not they let you control routing. Heroku's platform manual page about [HTTP Routing](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/http-routing) unfortunately does not have any references how you can configure "Virtual Directory" routing...

Hope it will give you further direction where to dig.